# how to do the pattern matching in RegEx?

Tags: java, regex

I have a sample request asking for enrollment info for various account id's coming from UI, Showing below.

`/api/v2/account/123/enroll?at_user=id_map:1345`

The only thing that keeps on varying with the request will be "123" and "1345". I need to look for a string (in java Servlet) that looks exactly as above but with varying numeric value.

For Example, if a request come as below

```
/api/v2/account/444/enroll?at_user=* // should not process

/api/v2/account/654/enroll?at_user=id_map:1432 // Should process it
```

I was thinking of RegEx, But i am new to RegEx. how to do the pattern matching in RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\d+` to match one or more digits. Since `?` is special regex meta character, you need to escape it in-order to match a literal `?` symbol.

```
"/api/v2/account/\\d+/enroll\\?at_user=id_map:\\d+"
```

ie,

```
if (string.matches("/api/v2/account/\\d+/enroll\\?at_user=id_map:\\d+"))
{ 
 // process
}
else
{
// don't process
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I tested it it's working. I need to apply to my code now

Answer (score 3):

you need:

```
"^/api/v2/account/\\d+/enroll\\?at_user=id_map:\\d+$"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "$" at the end and " ^" in the begining?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
if (yourString != null && 
    yourString.startsWith("/api/v2/account/654/enroll?at_user=id_map:")) {

     //do your thing
}
```